# as.integer makes characters NA

Tags: r, matrix, integer, na

I have some sequencing data for some biological samples. The file to read contains 7 columns first that contain characters, as they have gene names and codes etc. From the 8th column are my samples that contain count data, so a number assigned to a gene depending of how much of that gene is present in a given sample.

The problem is that the CSV file I have contains non-integer values and so I need to convert them into integers (`as.integer`).

This works absolutely find if I delete the columns that contain gene information etc. and have a matrix with only the values! However, I need the gene information and therefore the columns that contain this information, but if I carry out `as.integer` on the entire data frame, any characters get returned as NA and so I also lose all of this information!

I am struggling as I am guessing I should make the first 7 columns `as.characters`? Or apply the `as.integer` function to the 8th column up to the last, however I am struggling to think of the code to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `lapply()` to apply `as.integer()` to all except the first 7 columns?

```
df[, -seq(1, 7)] <- lapply(df[, -seq(1, 7)], as.integer)

#result
> df 
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7  c8  c9
1   G  F  Y  M  V  M  X 104  13
2   J  E  F  O  Q  V  H  67  11
3   N  Q  P  L  S  K  L 107 -13
4   U  I  C  E  M  F  Y 102 -14
5   E  X  Z  S  L  B  O 129   7
6   S  K  I  Y  Y  C  F 125  15
7   W  O  A  P  A  G  J  55  -2
8   M  S  H  C  J  J  V  30  17
9   L  G  X  N  N  L  B 129   7
10  B  N  V  G  Z  T  S  99 -12
```

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  c1 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
  c2 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
  c3 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
  c4 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
  c5 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
  c6 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
  c7 = sample(LETTERS, 10),
  c8 = rexp(10, rate = 0.01),
  c9 = rnorm(10, sd = 20)
)

> df
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7        c8         c9
1   G  F  Y  M  V  M  X 104.94389  13.939268
2   J  E  F  O  Q  V  H  67.88807  11.133264
3   N  Q  P  L  S  K  L 107.98811 -13.775114
4   U  I  C  E  M  F  Y 102.82469 -14.149903
5   E  X  Z  S  L  B  O 129.22616   7.291639
6   S  K  I  Y  Y  C  F 125.31054  15.370658
7   W  O  A  P  A  G  J  55.46414  -2.246924
8   M  S  H  C  J  J  V  30.12830  17.622155
9   L  G  X  N  N  L  B 129.31247   7.962118
10  B  N  V  G  Z  T  S  99.45558 -12.240528
```